HMAccessorySetupRequest.homeUniqueIdentifier dont work
let setupRequest = HMAccessorySetupRequest()
        setupRequest.homeUniqueIdentifier = home.uniqueIdentifier
        setupRequest.suggestedRoomUniqueIdentifier = home.rooms.first?.uniqueIdentifier
        setupRequest.suggestedAccessoryName = "test light"
        let hmSetupManager = HMAccessorySetupManager()
        hmSetupManager.performAccessorySetup(using: setupRequest, completionHandler: { result, error in
            print("result:\(result)")
            print("error:\(error)")
        })

I use HMAccessorySetupRequest and set other home.
But the accessory alaways add to primary home.
Why?
